# React native calling a function from a conditional statement inside onPress

Tags: javascript, react-native, if-statement

I have the following code but it does not work

The first part is working fine and zi get the alert but the second one ia not

> ```
> <Button onPress={ 
>
>      if (this.state.value===""){ alert("try again"); } else { this.functionToBeCalled }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working this way:

```js
onPress={() => {
    if (this.state.newRating===""){ alert("try again"); } 
    else { this.functionToBeCalled() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
onPress={() => {
    if (this.state.value===""){ alert("try again"); } 
    else { this.functionToBeCalled }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way of writing it would be

```js
onPress={() => {
  if(this.state.value!=="") return this.functionToBeCalled();
  alert("try again")  
}
```